# Git: How to create a remote repo from a local repo and push the local branches to the remote on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Subtle Git question here (at least for me).

I started developing some code, and before I did so I initialized a local repo.  But I could not push it to the GitHub repository.

I tried going into GitHub, and by so doing verified I have the account name and password correct.

In order to try to get some 'traction', I copied the two major files (via Github 'drop-and-drag') and thus created a repository remotely.

However, I can't push at all to the remote repo.  When I try, it asks my username and password - which I confirmed on my second computer are right - but it fails with "invalid username or password'.

How do I start with my local repo, and get its branches (master and develop) to have a backup copy of my project in the cloud?

Comment: You have to use SSH keys.

Comment: Sure?  I have another account on github, and it works without, asking for the login credentials each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion was right.  I had enabled 2 factor authentication (2FA) for this account.

Git commands start out right, but with 2FA the password you give when prompted is an SSH key, not your account password.  It's not at all obvious, but it will work then.

Details on how to do this are here:  https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-a-remotes-url#switching-remote-urls-from-ssh-to-https